# discord bot - delete all channels in a discord server using discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need to delete all the channels with a certain name in my discord server using discord js v13.

For example if there are 5 channels with the name "general" then I want to delete them and make sure that the rest of the channels don't get deleted. All the posts that I found were for v12.

I'm pretty new to discord.js, so I would appreciate some help!

This is my code:

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');

});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('YOUR_GUILD_ID');
    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => { // check each channel in guild your command was executed in
        if(channel.name == "general") channel.delete() // delete channel if its name is "general"
    })
})
```

should help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content === "!nuke"){
        message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
    }
});
```